# Virtualization Problem with Windows in virt-manager

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, clonezilla, virt-manager

I tried to virtualize a Windows physical HDD into a image file (qcow2) using clonezilla and it was perfectly copied the disk partitions in the image, but it don't want to boot the vm.

```
Hardware & Software Information :  
 - Two Monitor (one on each graphic card)
 - Geforce GTX 980
 - Geforce GTX 660
 - MSI XPOWER X99S AC
 - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz
 - Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64
```

[image: monitor_vm.png]

I created the image file with virt-manager and i copied the disk with the Windows partitions with Clonezilla.

I follow [this guide](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-setup-a-gaming-virtual-machine-with-gpu-passthrough-qemu-kvm-libvirt-and-vfio.1371980/) to use the vm without virt-manager but it seems it doesn't work if you don't create the UUID with virt-manager.

I'm running out of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another application, 
`qemu-img convert -p -O raw /dev/sdX vdisk1.img`
It can qcow too.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work, the same result as the image of my post appeared again.